# Passing multiple includes that contain spaces to grep

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I'm creating PowerShell and Bash scripts to standardise our usage of the former's `Get-ChildItem` and `Select-String` and the latter's `grep`.

As part of the Bash script, I'm taking command-line arguments, parsing the comma-delimited values for the filename includes (**plural**), and trying to pass them to Grep's `--include=` but encountering all sorts of difficulties.

Initially, I was trying to use brace expansion, but I abandoned this because (1) I couldn't get it to work and (2) I read that this technically isn't supported by grep and the proper solution is to use multiple includes anyway.

Now, I'm trying to use those multiple includes which I have managed to get working, but only if the value doesn't contain a space - if it does then the script does nothing, presumably because the values aren't quoted, but I haven't been able to get a quoted version working, even though copying and pasting the output of `$grepstring` in the shell works fine.

Here's a simplified version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

include="$1"

if [[ $include == *","* ]]; then
    IFS=',' read -r -a includearray <<< "$include"
    
    includemulti=""
    
    firstloop="yes"
    
    for element in "${includearray[@]}"
    do
        # Trim leading and trailing whitespace
        element="${element## }"
        element="${element%% }"
        
        if [[ "$firstloop" == "yes" ]]; then
            firstloop="no"
            includemulti+="--include=$element"
            # includemulti+="--include=\"$element\""
            # includemulti+="--include='"$element"'"
            # includemulti+='--include="'$element'"'
            # includemulti+='--include="'"$element"'"'
            # includemulti+="--include='$element'"
        else
            includemulti+=" --include=$element"
            # includemulti+=" --include=\"$element\""
            # includemulti+=" --include='"$element"'"
            # includemulti+=' --include="'$element'"'
            # includemulti+=' --include="'"$element"'"'
            # includemulti+=" --include='$element'"
        fi
    done
    
    grep -ERins $includemulti "<pattern>" "<path>"
    
    grepstring="grep -ERins $includemulti \"<pattern>\" \"<path>\""
    echo $grepstring
else
    grep -ERins --include="$include" "<pattern>" "<path>"
fi
```

Does work:

```
bash ~/test.sh 'Hello*.txt, *.sh'

bash ~/test.sh 'Hello W*.txt'
```

Does not work:

```
bash ~/test.sh 'Hello W*.txt, *.sh'
```

I'm starting to wonder if it's just easier to call `grep` multiple times with one include for each one...

Comment: "_I was trying to use brace expansion, but I abandoned this because […] I read that this technically isn't supported by grep_" - it's nothing to do with `grep`. A suitable shell will expand a brace pattern and supply the result as a set of arguments to whatever command is present.

Comment: Your `includemulti` variable splits, hence the issue.

Comment: see also [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373) (which also contains the case where it's just the command arguments and explains why it happens)

Comment: you _can_ brace expand e.g. `--include={foo,bar}` into `--include=foo --include=bar`. just that combining that with any sort of a variable is difficult to impossible in Bash (but maybe easier in other shells, though possibly still fishy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

When your input is: `'Hello W*.txt, *.sh'`, spaces would be used as delimiters. So your `includemulti` would be split to three words:

- `--include=Hello`
- `W*.txt`
- `--include=*.sh`

If you add `set -x` in your script before the `grep` command you'll see exactly how it gets executed and confirm what I said:

```
+ grep -ERins --include=Hello 'W*.txt' '--include=*.sh' <pattern> <path>
```

Even if you change the `includemulti+=` line and add quotes around the elements:

```
includemulti+=" --include=\"$element\""
```

It won't help, because `bash` will still use the spaces as word delimiters:

```
+ grep -ERins '--include="Hello' 'W*.txt"' '--include="*.sh"' <pattern> <path>
```

#### Solution 1

One possible solution that require less changes in your script would be to add the quotes around the the elements, **and** add the `eval` builtin before your `grep` command. From the `bash` man pages:

> **eval** [*arg ...*]
>
> The *args* are read and concatenated together into a single command.
> This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit
> status is returned as the value of **eval**. If there are no *args*,
> or only null arguments, **eval** returns 0.

So if you add `eval` before your grep command, effectively it would be like running:

```
bash -c 'grep -ERins --include="Hello W*.txt" --include="*.sh" <pattern> <path>'
```

And with `set -x` before the `grep` command you'll see two lines, the second one is the one actually getting executed:

```
+ eval grep -ERins '--include="Hello' 'W*.txt"' '--include="*.sh"' <pattern> <path>
++ grep -ERins '--include=Hello W*.txt' '--include=*.sh' <pattern> <path>
```

#### Solution 2

This is the more elegant solution. Instead of your loop, you modify the `includearray` array variable:

```
# Remove leading space from every element in the array
includearray=("${includearray[@]## }")
# Remove trailing space from every element in the array
includearray=("${includearray[@]%% }")
# Add --include= as the prefix of every element in the array                                                                                                                
includearray=("${includearray[@]/#/--include=}")
```

And then your `grep` command will look as follows:

```
grep -ERins "${includearray[@]}" <pattern> <path>
```

When you do it that way, you don't need to surround your elements by quotes, since every element in the `includearray` array will be treated as a single word (regardless of any spaces it has).

So your final code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

include="$1"

if [[ $include == *","* ]]; then
    IFS=',' read -r -a includearray <<< "$include"

    # Remove leading space from every element in the array
    includearray=("${includearray[@]## }")
    # Remove trailing space from every element in the array
    includearray=("${includearray[@]%% }")
    # Add --include= as the prefix of every element in the array                                                                                                                
    includearray=("${includearray[@]/#/--include=}")
    
    grep -ERins "${includearray[@]}" "<pattern>" "<path>"
else
    grep -ERins --include="$include" "<pattern>" "<path>"
fi
```

Comment: plus that `W*.txt` would expand to matching filenames if there were any

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building a string and applying `eval` to it, which is prone to unexpected errors due to quoting, whitespace, and other issues, you can use an array to build the set of arguments to `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
includesList="$1"
IFS=, read -ra includes <<<"$includesList"
# echo "! includesList=$includesList, includes=(${includes[@]}) !" >&2
[ 0 -eq "${#includes[@]}" ] && { echo "ERROR: Missing includes" >&2; exit 1; }

args=()
for include in "${includes[@]}"
do
    include="${include## }"
    include="${include%% }"
    args+=('--include' "$include")
done
# echo "! args=(${args[@]}) !" >&2

grep -EIins "${args[@]}" "<REpattern>" "<path>"
```

Usage:

```
chmod a+rx code

./code 'trick*'
./code 'trick*,house,truck*.sh'
./code 'Hello W*.txt, *.sh'
```

If you uncomment the two debugging `echo` statements you may be initially confused by the lack of quotes. The values themselves do not contain quotes to mark them out, so with your last example you'll get this:

```
! includesList=Hello W*.txt, *.sh, includes=(Hello W*.txt  *.sh) !
! args=(--include Hello W*.txt --include *.sh) !
```

Because it's a simplistic debugging statement it's not possible to see visually which of the the `args()` values are which. There are actually four array elements, `--include` x2 along with `Hello W*.txt` and `*.sh`. A more sophisticated "print array" routine could use a `printf '%q'` approach to output values suitably quoted, but I felt that was overkill here:

```
{ printf '! args=('; printf "'%q' " "${args[@]}"; printf ') !\n'; } >&2
```

Comment: Thanks, roaima. I've copy and pasted your code, and I get the same echo output, but, again, the actual grep still doesn't work / output anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @mythofechelon I'm sorry to hear that. It works for me with my examples. You did fix up `<REpattern>` (previously `<pattern>`) and `<path>` for the `grep` itself...?